# Ethernet doesn't work in Ubuntu while working in Windows on the same machine

Tags: networking, dual-boot, ethernet

I have dual boot system with Windows 10 and Ubuntu 15.10 installed. Everything worked well until last Ubuntu upgrade (or any other reason, I'm not sure here). Ethernet simply stopped working in Ubuntu while still works good in Windows.

I've tried manual setup instead of DHCP, but nothing. `sudo dhclient` hangs.

I've tried live images of Ubuntu 15.10 and 14.04, but no luck - in "try Ubuntu" mode I don't have connection.

My system:

```
> uname -a
Linux amaslenn-ubuntu 4.2.0-22-generic #27-Ubuntu SMP Thu Dec 17 22:57:08 UTC 2015 x86_64 x86_64 x86

> lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:  Ubuntu 15.10
Release:  15.10
Codename: wily
```

**`lspci -nn`**:

```
00:00.0 Host bridge [0600]: Intel Corporation 4th Gen Core Processor DRAM Controller [8086:0c00] (rev 06)
00:01.0 PCI bridge [0604]: Intel Corporation Xeon E3-1200 v3/4th Gen Core Processor PCI Express x16 Controller [8086:0c01] (rev 06)
00:02.0 Display controller [0380]: Intel Corporation Xeon E3-1200 v3/4th Gen Core Processor Integrated Graphics Controller [8086:0412] (rev 06)
00:03.0 Audio device [0403]: Intel Corporation Xeon E3-1200 v3/4th Gen Core Processor HD Audio Controller [8086:0c0c] (rev 06)
00:14.0 USB controller [0c03]: Intel Corporation 8 Series/C220 Series Chipset Family USB xHCI [8086:8c31] (rev 05)
00:16.0 Communication controller [0780]: Intel Corporation 8 Series/C220 Series Chipset Family MEI Controller #1 [8086:8c3a] (rev 04)
00:19.0 Ethernet controller [0200]: Intel Corporation Ethernet Connection I217-V [8086:153b] (rev 05)
00:1a.0 USB controller [0c03]: Intel Corporation 8 Series/C220 Series Chipset Family USB EHCI #2 [8086:8c2d] (rev 05)
00:1b.0 Audio device [0403]: Intel Corporation 8 Series/C220 Series Chipset High Definition Audio Controller [8086:8c20] (rev 05)
00:1d.0 USB controller [0c03]: Intel Corporation 8 Series/C220 Series Chipset Family USB EHCI #1 [8086:8c26] (rev 05)
00:1f.0 ISA bridge [0601]: Intel Corporation H87 Express LPC Controller [8086:8c4a] (rev 05)
00:1f.2 SATA controller [0106]: Intel Corporation 8 Series/C220 Series Chipset Family 6-port SATA Controller 1 [AHCI mode] [8086:8c02] (rev 05)
00:1f.3 SMBus [0c05]: Intel Corporation 8 Series/C220 Series Chipset Family SMBus Controller [8086:8c22] (rev 05)
01:00.0 VGA compatible controller [0300]: NVIDIA Corporation GK104 [GeForce GTX 760] [10de:1187] (rev a1)
01:00.1 Audio device [0403]: NVIDIA Corporation GK104 HDMI Audio Controller [10de:0e0a] (rev a1)
```

**`ifconfig -a`**:

```
eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr e0:3f:49:6f:61:09
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:13 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:131 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000
          RX bytes:1114 (1.1 KB)  TX bytes:27153 (27.1 KB)
          Interrupt:20 Memory:f7800000-f7820000

lo        Link encap:Local Loopback
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
          inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:65536  Metric:1
          RX packets:771 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:771 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0
          RX bytes:63627 (63.6 KB)  TX bytes:63627 (63.6 KB)
```

**`cat /etc/network/interfaces`**:

```
# interfaces(5) file used by ifup(8) and ifdown(8)
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

#auto eth0
#iface eth0 inet static
#address 192.168.1.12
#netmask 255.255.255.0
#gateway 192.168.1.1
#network 192.168.1.0
#broadcast  192.168.1.255
#dns-nameservers 8.8.8.8 8.8.4.4
```

**`sudo lshw -C net`**:

```
  *-network
       description: Ethernet interface
       product: Ethernet Connection I217-V
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 19
       bus info: pci@0000:00:19.0
       logical name: eth0
       version: 05
       serial: e0:3f:49:6f:61:09
       size: 1Gbit/s
       capacity: 1Gbit/s
       width: 32 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
       configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=e1000e driverversion=3.2.5-k duplex=full firmware=0.13-4 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes port=twisted pair speed=1Gbit/s
       resources: irq:27 memory:f7800000-f781ffff memory:f783d000-f783dfff ioport:f080(size=32)
```

Hope somebody can help me figure it out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason was in Intel's driver for Windows.
Installing it without any additional services ([see screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vqXQj.png)) solves my issue.